# Will limits in Provisioned throughput change is applicable even after enabling the auto scaling feature on dynamo db table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, autoscaling

Like it says in the documents we can only decrease the provision through put 4 times(normal) and total 9 times in a day with some conditions,    http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html#limits-provisioned-throughput-min-max

will that be applicable even after we have enabled auto scaling feature for our table.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-auto-scaling-for-amazon-dynamodb/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for my question was their within the aws documentation

it says,
As noted on the Limits in DynamoDB page, you can increase provisioned capacity as often as you would like and as high as you need (subject to per-account limits that we can increase on request). You can decrease capacity up to nine times per day for each table or global secondary index.

so as of now, only 4 times or 9 times(**some conditions) a day it will decrease the throughput capacity.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html#limits-provisioned-throughput-min-max

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this had changed since the question was asked but you can actually change up to 27 times in a day:

"A decrease is allowed up to four times, anytime per day. A day is defined according to Universal Coordinated Time (UTC). Additionally, if there was no decrease in the past hour, an additional decrease is allowed. This effectively brings the maximum number of decreases in a day to 27 times (4 decreases in the first hour, and 1 decrease for each of the subsequent 1-hour windows in a day)."

Source:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html#default-limits-throughput-capacity-modes